# cd works in shell but not in script

Tags: shell-script, cd-command

I frequently have to `cd` from `$HOME` to a particular long directory path. So I thought I'd put a cdscript in $HOME to make getting there a little quicker.

**cdscript:**

```
#!/bin/sh
directory="/some/big/long directory path/that/I/use/frequently"
cd "$directory"
```

Set permissions:
`chmod 700 cdscript`

`./cdscript` doesn't do anything. What am I missing? (Yes, those spaces in the path exist, and I can copy and paste the exact individual lines in the shell with success, so the path exists too). Also, is it more Unixey to just make a symbolic link to the directory instead of the above script, and `cd` to the link instead?

Comment: It could be because of spaces. Add `-x` at the first line: `#!/bin/sh -x`and runt it again. It starts debug mode, and you can see what it's really running.

Comment: Try again without the double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just doing

```
./cdscript
```

won't work. basically you forked a new shell, in which you cd, then the shell (and new working dir) exit.

You need to use

```
. ./cdscript
```

(there is a leading dot, and a space)

The first dot means : run `./cdscript` as if I typed it.
The second dot is needed if . is not in your `PATH` var.

Answer (score 4):

You would be better of creating an alias for this within your shell. For example in `.bashrc`, you could put;

```
alias cdscript='cd /really/long/file/path/'
```

Comment: Ok, but why is an alias **better** than a symbolic link in this case? (i.e. is this the *best* solution, and if so why? - not trying to be obnoxious, just genuinely curious and trying to use the shell the best I can)

Comment: A symlink would add an entry into your directory ; the alias wouldn't. It keeps the directory clean of "practical symlinks", yet again, it could also be a good idea depending on your case.

Comment: I agree it's cleaner than having specific scripts to change into a directory, there may be a need to have a script if you're doing something more complex but for a simple ```cd``` an alias would, in my mind, a cleaner-simpler solution.

Comment: I use symlinks, because then I can use them from all programs, not just the shell. However alias solves the question directly.

Answer (score 1):

The script changes your current working directory but then it is restored upon exit.  Instead of typing

```
cdscript
```

try typing

```
 . cdscript
```

to run your script for the desired result.